# Query must be a SELECT

Tags: mariadb, select

I try to do a select union with order by but it seem like order by can not use union.

I receive following message

> Query must be a SELECT

This is my code

```
(SELECT
  `tabsales_action`.responsible as "Responsible:data:200",
  `tabsales_action`.action_type as "Action Type:data:200",  
  count(*) as "Nb:Int:60"
FROM
  `tabsales_action` 
WHERE
  `tabsales_action`.workflow_state = 'To do'
GROUP BY 
  `tabsales_action`.responsible,   
  `tabsales_action`.action_type
ORDER BY 
  `tabsales_action`.responsible )
UNION (SELECT `tabmfi_loan_action`.responsible,
`tabmfi_loan_action`.action_type FROM  `tabmfi_loan_action`
WHERE
  `tabmfi_loan_action`.workflow_state = 'To do'
GROUP BY 
  `tabmfi_loan_action`.responsible,   
  `tabmfi_loan_action`.action_type
ORDER BY 
  `tabmfi_loan_action`.responsible)
UNION (SELECT `tabin_house_credit_action`.responsible,
`tabin_house_credit_action`.action_type FROM `tabin_house_credit_action`
WHERE
  `tabin_house_credit_action`.workflow_state = 'To do'
GROUP BY 
  `tabin_house_credit_action`.responsible,   
  `tabin_house_credit_action`.action_type
ORDER BY 
  `tabin_house_credit_action`.responsible)
UNION (SELECT `tabservices_planning`.responsible,
`tabservices_planning`.action_type FROM `tabservices_planning`
WHERE
  `tabservices_planning`.workflow_state = 'To do'
GROUP BY 
  `tabservices_planning`.responsible,   
  `tabservices_planning`.action_type
ORDER BY 
  `tabservices_planning`.responsible)
UNION (SELECT `accounting_action`.responsible,
`accounting_action`.action_type FROM `accounting_action`
WHERE
  `accounting_action`.workflow_state = 'To do'
GROUP BY 
  `accounting_action`.responsible,   
  `accounting_action`.action_type
ORDER BY 
  `accounting_action`.responsible)
```

What can I do?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` has to be put in another query around the inner `UNION`s, BUT there's a problem - the first query in your `UNION` returns 3 columns, the rest 2 columns.

Comment: I got on Mariadb ,what can i do with that

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few issues here.

When using the `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operator, each query must return the same number of columns. The first query in your list has three columns in the `SELECT` but the queries that come later only have two. You can create a static value for these if you need to, something like this (using the second query as an example);

```
 SELECT 
`tabmfi_loan_action`.responsible,
`tabmfi_loan_action`.action_type,
'' --Use a zero length string
FROM  `tabmfi_loan_action`
```

You cannot order your queries that you use with the `UNION` operator, you'll have to take your `ORDER BY` statements out. If you do need to order the result then you will have to use your current statement (all of it) as a `subquery` and `ORDER` in an outer `SELECT`. Something like this

```
SELECT
a.Field1
,a.Field2
FROM
    (
        SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1
        UNION 
        SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table2
    ) a
ORDER BY a.Field1
```

Try fixing these first and see if this resolves your issues.

Comment: The first paragraph is correct. But for the second, mind that `(select ... order by x) union (select ... order by y) ;` and `(select ... order by x) union (select ... order by y) order by z;` are both valid syntax in mysql.

Comment: Gotcha, cheers.